# How to automatically compute space between the dots in \hdotsfor

Tags: spacing, matrices

If you take a closer look at the included picture, you will notice the two vertical dotted lines are crooked and they are caused by the `\hdotsfor[6]{5} \\` (see below MWE). So, is there a way to automatically compute the space between the dots generated by an `\hdotsfor` in any size of a matrix to resolve such a crooked vertical dotted lines? Please note, the 5 units of `\cdots` that form the horizontal dotted line above the `\hdotsfor[6]{5} \\` line are there as a reference only to show what I want an `\hdotsfor` to exactly generate the dots. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
        a_{1}
        \begin{vmatrix}
                b_{2} &c_{2} &\cdot &\cdot &k_{2} \\
                b_{3} &c_{3} &\cdot &\cdot &k_{3} \\
                \cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot &\cdot \\
                \hdotsfor[6]{5} \\
                b_{n} &c_{n} &\cdot &\cdot &k_{n}
        \end{vmatrix}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think they'll ever line up with `\hdotsfor` in this way since the column widths are different. You'll have to create a macro to replicate `$\cdot$`s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is probably sufficient for your needs. It sets the first dot using `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cdot}`, since `\multicolumn` has to be the first (expanded) entry within a cell. Subsequent `\cdot`s are set as part of a replication of `& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cdot}` over the remaining columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\cdotsfor}[1]{
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cdot}% Place first dot
  \replicate{\inteval{#1-1}}{& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cdot}}% Place remaining dots
}

\begin{document}

\[
  a_1
  \begin{vmatrix}
    b_2 & c_2 & \cdot & \cdot & k_2 \\
    b_3 & c_3 & \cdot & \cdot & k_3 \\
    \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\ % For reference
    \cdotsfor{5} \\
    b_n & c_n & \cdot & \cdot & k_n
  \end{vmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. It works as I wanted and thank you very much! Just for posterity sake (or perhaps I should create another topic), would it be possible for you to tailor your code to accommodate different width of any columns (if one column is wider), i.e. 1st column from (b_2 b_3 ... b_n)' changed to (\alpha+b_2 \beta+b_3 \kappa+b_n)' that causes this column become much wider and to be filled with more dots and still be able to form the straight vertical dotted lines?

Comment: @user91822: No. My solution just prints a number of `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\cdot}`s, so the dots will be spread out in the same manner the columns are, with one `\cdot` per column.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not possible as `\hdotsfor` is a spanning cell like `\multicolumn` (actually it *is* `\multicolumn`) so it spans the specified number of columns with equally spaced dots. However the position of the single `\cdot` entries in other rows depends on the width of the entries in the array information which is not readily available while constructing the spanning entry.